# JPA on JBoss As 6.X or 7

Tags: jboss, jpa-2.0

I m trying to find good reference for how to do JPA project (with EJB 3.x).

Its been very difficult for me to find how to configure persistance unit according to jBoss. (in GlassFish its just a piece of cake).

is anyone of you know good reference

Comment: Did you get your issue resolved? I'm porting my app to Glassfish right now and am hoping all i will need to do is update my data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ported my app that I developed on NetBeans from Glassfish 3 to JBoss 6. I had to [disable JTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300316/can-not-create-entitymanager-factory-bc-jta-tx-manager-requiered) for the persistance to work but since I don't need that at the moment something is better than nothing.

I am using container managed security and documented my configuration in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318494/login-issue-with-databaseserverloginmodule-in-jboss-6).

I configured my JBoss 6 datasource by placing mysql-ds.xml into `$JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy`. Here are contents:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/thor_ds</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thor</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>mjolnir</user-name>
    <password>mjolnir</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>
        org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
    </exception-sorter-class-name>
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Unlike Glassfish, in JBoss 6, I had to declare each of my persistence classes explicitly. Here is my Persistence XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="AvengersPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <!--<persistence-unit name="AvengersPU" transaction-type="JTA">-->
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/thor_ds</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/thor_ds</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>avenger.Grouptable</class>
    <class>avenger.MyUser</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between application servers in terms of JPA. Just do the same thing you did for Glasfish.

The only difference is configuring the DataSource - but there are enough google results for that.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring your persistence.xml you should be ready to go as JPA is a Java EE standard and should be application server independent.