# Can not create EntityManager factory bc JTA tx manager requiered

Tags: jpa, jboss, persistence.xml

I can not build my entity manager factory and the error I get is "chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA Transaction Manager". Can anyone advise what i have to configure to get past this? FYI I'm using Jboss 6, no spring.

Here is my **persistance.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AvengersPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/thor_ds</jta-data-source>
    <class>avenger.Grouptable</class>
    <class>avenger.MyUser</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is partial stacktrace...

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: AvengersPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48) [:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32) [:1.0.0.Final]
        at avenger.Utils.getEntityManager(Utils.java:49) [:]
        at avenger.UserBean.updateUserList(UserBean.java:136) [:]
        at avenger.UserBean.startup(UserBean.java:43) [:]
        ... 68 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA TransactionManager
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:390) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906) [:3.6.6.Final]
        ... 74 more
```

Full stack trace is here: http://pastebin.ca/2166417

Answer (score 0):

Here is an non ideal answer which I will use in the meanwhile.

specify a non jta datasource:

```
<non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/thor_ds</non-jta-data-source>
```

change transaction type from JTA to RESOURCE_LOCAL

```
<persistence-unit name="AvengersPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Here is a [discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58527-transaction-type-quot-JTA-quot-quot-RESOURCE_LOCAL-quot) on the subject: